# Python Threading: threading.Thread().start() works, _thread.start_new_thread() doesn't

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to achieve a centralized server with multiple clients connected. The connection should be kept alive.

I've experimented with multiple clients using threads until now, but when the socket is "busy" with a client, another client can't connect in that socket.

This code represents the server script:

```py
import socket
import threading

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 54321


def request_handler(conn, addr):
    with conn:
        print(conn, addr)

        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))

            if not data:
                break

            conn.sendall(data)


def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()

        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print('Connected with', addr[0], ':', str(addr[1]))

            t = threading.Thread(target=request_handler(conn, addr), daemon=True)
            t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code represents the client part:

```py
import socket


host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 54321


def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, port))
        while True:
            data = input('Type data: ')

            if not data:
                break

            s.send(str.encode(data))

            res = s.recv(1024)
            print('Server Response:', res.decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A client can write many messages, and the connection stays open, but if I use another client, this can't connect with the server until the first client closes the connection.

But what I want is that the second client can do the same as the first, and so on, with other clients. How to do this?

There is a solution other than creating multiple ports?

## UPDATE

I've modified the server script, using _thread.start_new_thread, and now it works. But I can't understand why.

Modified server.py

```py
import socket
from _thread import start_new_thread

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 54321


def request_handler(conn, addr):
    with conn:
        print(conn, addr)

        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))

            if not data:
                break

            conn.sendall(data)


def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()

        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print('Connected with', addr[0], ':', str(addr[1]))

            start_new_thread(request_handler, (conn, addr))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To summarize, with `start_new_thread(request_handler, (conn, addr))` the second client can connect to the server, and send messages; with `threading.Thread(target=request_handler(conn, addr)).start()` it doesn't connect to the server, but no error is raised.

When I use the `threading.Thread.start()` the Main tread is waiting that the #1 client thread is stopped, so it's hybernated, and doesn't start the #2 client thread;  instead the `_thread.start_new_thread()` is work fine. But the `threading.Thread.start()` implements the `_thread.start_new_thread`, so what's happening here?

Comment: Use multiple ports instead of one?

Comment: It could be a mess, think that there are 100+ clients, I need 100+ different ports and match them... can you provide an example?

Comment: Create a function that starts listening on a new port each time, and if required, a mapping of ports to client addresses. Might add some overhead, but it wouldn't be a mess

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was using the threading.Thread constructor in the wrong way:

The constructor was invoking the request_handler instead of referencing it.

So, instead of:

> t = threading.Thread(target=request_handler(conn, addr))

the right way is:

> t = threading.Thread(target=request_handler, args=(conn, addr))

so that the threads can run in parallel.